# How do I get mouseover event to work on both p and parent div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a p tag nested in a div tag. The div tag has a mouseover event handler attached to it, the p tag has no event handler. **I want to be able to trigger the mouseover event no matter where I in the div tag I mouse over**. At this point the mouseover is triggered differently depending on whether I'm over the text or over another section of the div tag.

```
function btnColorChange(evt){
        var evtTrgt = evt.target;
        evtTrgt.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(41, 82, 204)";
        evtTrgt.style.color="rgb(233, 234, 235)";
        evtTrgt.style.cursor = "pointer";

        setTimeout(function(){
            evtTrgt.style.color = "#330000";
            evtTrgt.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(41, 82, 163,.5)";
        }, 800);
    }

    var the_btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_ovrly");
    for (var i = 0; i < the_btns.length; i++){
        the_btns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
            btnColorChange(event);
        }, true);
    }
```

HTML - snippet containing the relevant code

```
    <div id="chrts_ovrly">
        <div id="btn_ovrly_l" class="btn_ovrly"><p>L text</p></div>
        <div id="btn_ovrly_r" class="btn_ovrly"><p>R text</p></div>
    </div>
```

Button descriptions:
1: default button state
2: button when mouseover the div but not the text
3: button after you mouseover the text - text color changed
4: button after initial mouseover of text and now mouseover the div only
5: button after initial mouseover of text and now mouseover the text only

[image: Button before mouseover]
[image: Button with div mouseover the same with text mouseover]
[image: Button after mouseover text]
[image: Button on 2nd mouseover of text (on div) after 1st text mouseover]
[image: Button on 2nd mouseover of text (on text) after 1st text mouseover]
I think it has something to do with event bubbling capturing but I'm not sure. Any help so that the mouseovers are consistent would be greatful.

One more piece of information, I also have a click event attached to the div tag. The click event works while I click on the div, but it doesn't work when I click when my mouse is over the text.

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't use CSS hover for this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual to set a timeout that undoes the mouseover style while the mouse is potentially still in the target space.  Are you maybe wanting something more along this line:

```
function btnColorChange(evt){
    var evtTrgt = evt.target;
    evtTrgt.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(41, 82, 204)";
    evtTrgt.style.color="rgb(233, 234, 235)";
    evtTrgt.style.cursor = "pointer";
    evtTrgt.addEventListener("mouseout", undo);
}

var c = document.getElementById("chrts_ovrly")
c.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
        btnColorChange(event);
    }, true);

function undo(evt) {
    var evtTrgt = evt.target;
    evtTrgt.style.color = "yellow";
    evtTrgt.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    evtTrgt.removeEventListener("mouseout", undo);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it still doesn't solve help me solve how the mouseover is triggered depending on  if it is over the text in the div or just the div. Can you provide more information about where to put the remove event listener? Thanks

Comment: I think I'm not understanding what behavior you want to see.  Are you trying to get the text in the inner <p> to behave differently than the containing divs?

Comment: Do you maybe mean you want the entire outer div to receive the behavior as a block?  If so, replace the two instances of `evtTrgt = evt.target` with this:
`var evtTrgt = evt.currentTarget;`

Comment: I want the text in the <p> to behave the same as the containing div. Currently there are 3 different things that happen depending on what you mouseover.If I mouseover/hover over the edge of the containing div tag, the background color of the div  and the p tag change to a dark blue and the text changes to white. When I mouseout, they all revert to their original color. But if I mouseover the text, only the text background changes and when I mouseout, the text background is stays the same.

Comment: Are you seeing that behavior here:
[https://jsfiddle.net/crewman/jgr0kwxz/](https://jsfiddle.net/crewman/jgr0kwxz/)

Comment: Your currentTarget recommendation worked. Thanks. I hadn't used the currentTarget before.